# MySQL Update con SUM y Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, update, sum

Hola comapeñeros les planteo mi duda.

Actualmente cuento con 2 tablas, Users y Solicitud_de_vacaciones.

Estoy requiriendo guardar la sumatoria de los dias solicitados en la tabla solicitud_de_vacaciones agrupadas por id_usuario en la tabla Users.diasUsados.

Tabla solicitud_de_vacaciones

[image: Tabla solicitud_de_vacaciones]

Tabla Users

[image: Tabla Users]

la sumatoria y el group by con un select los he logrado de esta manera

```
SELECT solicitud_de_vacaciones.id_usuario , SUM(solicitud_de_vacaciones.totaldias) FROM solicitud_de_vacaciones where solicitud_de_vacaciones.id_estado=2 GROUP BY solicitud_de_vacaciones.id_usuario;
```

Ahora lo que no consigo es como hacer el update de esa sumatoria en la tabla Users.diasUsados

Comment: Hola. No entiendo tu problema. ¿Qué es lo que quieres actualizar concretamente? ¿De qué modo debe lanzarse esa actualización? ¿Qué has intentado? Me suena que lo mejor para esto sería lanzar un evento diario que vaya restando días de vacaciones a quienes estén en vacaciones. Y, si fuera tú, sacaría esa información de la tabla `Users`

Answer (score 0):

He logrado hacerlo de la siguiente forma

```
UPDATE users o INNER JOIN ( SELECT solicitud_de_vacaciones.id_usuario, SUM(solicitud_de_vacaciones.totaldias)
```

AS sumadias FROM solicitud_de_vacaciones
WHERE solicitud_de_vacaciones.id_estado = 2
GROUP BY solicitud_de_vacaciones.id_usuario ) t ON o.id = t.id_usuario SET o.diasUsados = t.sumadias;

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Es una forma de resolver las sumas de días utilizados un tanto extraña, pero si lo que quieres es hacerlo tal cual pides, sería algo como lo que sige. Se trata de que la consulta que adelantabas (y que calcula la suma de días usados de cada usuario junto a su código) sea el valor que das al UPDATE de Usuarios con JOIN a esa tabla de solicitudes (para que empareje el id_usuario en cada una de ellas)...

```
UPDATE Users usu 
    JOIN (
        SELECT solicitud_de_vacaciones.id_usuario,
           SUM(solicitud_de_vacaciones.totaldias) AS sumaTotalDias
        FROM solicitud_de_vacaciones 
        WHERE solicitud_de_vacaciones.id_estado=2 
        GROUP BY solicitud_de_vacaciones.id_usuario
    ) usados ON usu.id=usados.id_usuario 
    SET usu.diasUsados=usados.sumaTotalDias
```

Espero que te valga, al menos para lo que quieres